# Ajustar span dentro de link

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Possuo um botão e dentro dela possuo a uma tag `i` com um icone do `font-awesome` e dentro do `i` um `span` com o texto (sem o `span` o icone ficava em cima e o texto embaixo).

[image: atual]

O que eu preciso é uma maneira de posicionar esse `span` **4px** para cima, pois ele tem **20px** de distancia do topo e somente **16px** de distancia do bottom. `Padding` e `margim` não surgem efeito neste `span`

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


.button-entrar {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .7rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: .7rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.button-entrar::before,
.button-entrar::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: black;
}

.button-entrar span::before,
.button-entrar span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: black;
}

.button-entrar:hover::before,
.button-entrar:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.button-entrar:hover span::before,
.button-entrar:hover span::after {
  height: 100%;
}

.button-entrar::after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button-entrar span::after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button-entrar::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button-entrar span::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button-entrar:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="js-scroll button-entrar" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"><span class="pl-4">Entrar</span></i></a>
</li>
```

---

### EDIT

Após aplicar `position:relative` no span, a borda do hover ta saindo nele e não no botao.

[image: depois do position relative]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciona se você colocar um `position: relative` e um `top: -2px`:

```
.button-entrar span{
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

> Só que nesse caso, você deve movê-lo apenas 2px (metade da diferença
>   de 4px, ficando 18px em cima e 18px embaixo).

O span é um elemento inline. Movê-lo utilizando as propriedades `left`, `right`, `top` ou `bottom`, ele precisa de um `position: relative|absolute|fixed`. Para aplicar `margin` ou `padding`, ele precisa ser `inline-block` ou `block`. Mas o mais indicado, neste caso, é o `top` (ou `bottom`), porque se usar `margin` ou `padding`, irá mover também o ícone alinhado a ele.

### Questão do hover

Como você já usou os pseudos no `<a>` e não pode usar no `span` com `position relative` porque senão as linhas verticais do hover ficarão presas dentro do span, e também não pode colocar no `i` do ícone caso contrário o ícone não será exibido, a única alternativa que vejo é criar um span vazio no início do link:

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="js-scroll button-entrar" href="#">
      <span></span>
      <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt">
         <span class="pl-4">Entrar</span>
      </i>
   </a>
</li>
```

E criar os pseudos nesse span vazio:

```
.button-entrar > span::before,
.button-entrar > span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: black;
}
```

Note que o símbolo `>` irá apontar apenas pro span filho direto do link.

E alterar também o primeiro código da resposta para:

```
.button-entrar i span{
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

Para apontar para o outro span dentro do `i` do ícone;

Comment: muito obrigado, assim ele alinha, porém acaba acontecendo do hover pegar nele também e subir 2 bordas verticais, sabe como posso resolver isso ?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com um print de como ficou depois de adicionar `position:relative`

Comment: editei a pergunta.

Comment: Veja as alterações.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado